# Can I transform ckeditor into what Wikipedia Site use?

Tags: ckeditor

**What type of Text editor Wikipedia uses actually??**
[image: wikipedia's text editor]

The editor have inline commands like `=title=` for the topic sentence we see in wiki page. I am in need of creating a text editor like that for instance `**boldtext**` to be bold.

What I mean is how to make `**xxx**` , `***xxx***` or `=xxx=`a thing in Text editors.

**Stackoverflow** also uses similar text editor.

**I have an idea thought**
I am thinking can i say: (in php)

```
if (*detects the special characters*) {
    *bold the text*;
}
```

does it works?